# Concatenating two columns where one contains nulls

Tags: sql-server

I have a view on SQL 2012 where I am trying to concatenate 2 nvarchar columns. It returns nulls if one of the values are null.

I have tried the concat function, I have tried `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF`
I have tried to use isnull(column name) but still it is returning nulls

Here is my query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Assignment
                        ,[Document Number]+[Dunning Block] AS [Document Number]
                        ,[Document Type]
                        ,[Document Date]
                        ,[Special G/L Indicator]
                        ,[Amount in local currency]
                        ,[Local Currency]
                        ,[Clearing Document]
                        ,Text
                        ,Account
                        ,Reference
                        ,[Dunning block]
                        ,[Invoice reference]
                        ,SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 1, 4) AS Year
                        ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 1, 4) = '2013' 
                            THEN CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 6, 2) = '01' 
                                THEN CASE WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 9, 2) AS integer) > 25 THEN '02' 
                                        ELSE SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 6, 2) END 
                                ELSE SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 6, 2) END
                            ELSE SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 6, 2) END AS Period
                        , SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 9, 2) AS Day
FROM dbo.Zcustage
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use  CONCAT

```
CONCAT[Document Number],[Dunning Block])
```

CONCAT Ignores nulls

> CONCAT takes a variable number of string arguments and concatenates them into a single string. It requires a minimum of two input values; otherwise, an error is raised. All arguments are implicitly converted to string types and then concatenated. Null values are implicitly converted to an empty strin

Answer (score 0):

`SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF` would only work for concatenating  values and NULL- if all values are NULL, you'll still get NULL. I suspect both columns have NULL values in, despite your question title - any of your approaches probably would have worked if you had just inspected the data.

`ISNULL` should work fine for your situation, but make sure you do it on both columns involved that could be nullable:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Assignment,
                         ISNULL([Document Number],'') + ISNULL([Dunning Block], '') AS [Document Number],
                         [Document Type],
                         [Document Date],
                         [Special G/L Indicator],
                         [Amount in local currency],
                         [Local Currency],
                         [Clearing Document],
                         Text,
                         Account,
                         Reference,
                         [Dunning block],
                         [Invoice reference],
                         SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 1, 4) AS Year,
                         CASE
                           WHEN SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 1, 4) = '2013' THEN
                             CASE
                               WHEN SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 6, 2) = '01' THEN
                                 CASE
                                   WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 9, 2) AS INTEGER) > 25 THEN '02'
                                   ELSE SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 6, 2)
                                 END
                               ELSE SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 6, 2)
                             END
                           ELSE SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 6, 2)
                         END AS Period,
                         SUBSTRING(strDoc_Date, 9, 2) AS Day
FROM   dbo.Zcustage
```

On a side note, using TOP 100 PERCENT here is a no-op - it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need ISNULL

```
ISNULL(YourNullableField,'')
```